# .NET Core JWT Bearer Authentication - IssuerSigningKey is not being validated

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt

I'm authenticating a .net core controller like so:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
       .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddJwtBearer(options =>
       {
           options.Authority = "https://accounts.google.com";
           options.Audience = "123232323.apps.googleusercontent.com";

           options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
           {
               ValidateIssuer = true,
               ValidIssuer = "accounts.google.com",
               ValidateAudience = true,
               ValidAudience = "123232323.apps.googleusercontent.com",
               ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
               IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ANYTHING IN HERE !!!"))
           };
       });
```

I'm getting an id token from Google, and calling the endpoint (passing it in the header as Bearer)

Authentication succeeds, no matter what I put into IssuerSigningKey, even though ValidateIssuerSIgningKey = true.

Why is this? Shouldn't it be using this "secret key" to validate the JWT (id token)?

Comment: Sorry Phil, I'll delete the other one

Answer (score 0):

You are never meant to send an ID-token to the AddJwtBearer handler in ASP.NET Core. JWtBearer only deals with access tokens and the ID-token is typically only used to create the local session in the client application.

Comment: Are you sure? My client app gets an ID-token (in JWT) from google via javascript, and I send it to a back end API in the header, so the API knows who the user is

Comment: Yes, see https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/id-tokens  Also, a think to look out for is that the ID-token has a short lifetime, in some system, like 5 minutes and there is no way to "refresh/renew" an Id-token, you can only do that for access tokens. Then, you should not sent tokens via the browser, as the browser is insecure, watch this video why https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw

Comment: Thank you Tore I'll check out those resources.  I should mention that I don't want to call any Google API's, I just want my vue.js SPA to authenticate someone using google, and pass that authentication to my own API (so my API can store their email address).
My understanding is access tokens and refresh tokens are just for calling Google API's

Answer (score 0):

something to consider, if you specify options.Authority, signing key is retrieved from the well known url.